# c#: BluetoothLe in WPF: some classes/methods not found

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm writing a WPF Application (not an UWP) and I need to get BluetoothLE running.

I added the Bluetooth-usings:

```
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth;
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile;
```

and I added the references to **C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll**
and to **C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Facade\Windows.WinMD**.

But now two errors occure:

```
 var gattServicesResult = await device.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(new Guid(RX_SERVICE_UUID));
```

gives the error **'BluetoothLedevice' does not contain a definition for 'GetGattServicesForUuidAsync' [...] (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

and

```
GattWriteResult result =
                await characteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorWithResultAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);
```

gives the error **The type or namespace name 'GattWriteResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

I also tried UwpDesktop.

Any idea whats goind on? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Accroding to the most popular method, you should add references

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.16299.0\Windows.winmd`

and

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll`

to your project. But if you do this way, you will find some of the methods missing.
So instead of adding

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.16299.0\Windows.winmd`

we can add references

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Facade\Windows.WinMD`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract\3.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd`

and

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\6.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd`

to your project. This way works, I've been using it in my WPF project and everything works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add a reference to a specific version, for example

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.16299.0\Windows.winmd

I don't know if this is the right way to solve this problem but it should works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17901071)

Comment: You're right but I don't have sufficient reputation. By the way by doing this I solved the same problem